# Xcode doesn't crash on vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, c++11

Why doesn't Xcode crash with this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> vec(3);
    cout << vec[4];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  It doesn't have to crash.  It could become self aware and take over the world.

Comment: If you want bounds checking in your vectors, use `vec.at(4)` rather than `vec[4]`. Then it will throw an exception on out of bounds. Otherwise, in C++ you don't pay for what you don't use.

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behaviour (which this is) is not guaranteed to crash your program. It is in fact not defined to do any specific thing.
It may crash.
It may get deleted by the compiler.
It may do exactly what you intended.
It may delete all your files.
It means that your entire program is undefined and the code may even engage in time travel: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/

It is *undefined*.

The compiler may warn you about it or it may not. 
It is your responsability to just *not do that*.

You may enable flags such as `-Wall` and `-Wextra` for the clang and gcc compilers or `/W4` for Visual Studio. That *may* cause them to warn about this (and/or other stupid things you may be doing) but there is no guarantee. You can also use tools such as clang-tidy (http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy), Address Sanitizer (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) & Undefined Behaviour Sanitizer (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) or Valgrind (http://valgrind.org/) or cppcheck (http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) which can help find even more problems. But there is still no guarantee that you'll find all problems (although the compiler warnings and tools sure do help) - sometimes you simply have to *know what you are doing* and *don't write code with undefined behaviour*. And as others have already noted in comments, if you want runtime exceptions on out-of-bounds conditions; use the `at()` member function (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Comment: But what should I do if I want to make program warn me? Maybe I should add some compilation flags?

Comment: @Subirdcom I believe my updated answer answers that. Are you still not clear on this or could you accept the answer?